# Page ratings require Two Factor Authentication

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using PHP SDK to fetch page ratings for different pages. I am able to fetch ratings from an App Page on facebook by hitting the

`{page_id}/ratings`

endpoint for the App Page. But when I hit the same endpoint for a restaurant page I get the following error

> Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException
> (#200) User does not have sufficient administrative permission for this action on this page. If the page business requires Two Factor Authentication, the user also needs to enable Two Factor Authentication.

Does anyone have any idea why might this be happenning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was not related to the error at all.

The problem was that I was passing the wrong Page Id from my code for the second page in the
`{page_id}\ratings`
endpoint.

Anyone who comes across such error, do check that you are passing the right page id and page access token.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get ratings of Pages you own, with a Page Token of the Page in question.

Comment: Both the pages are owned by me. I have the admin access to the pages.

Comment: did you use a page token with the correct permissions?

Comment: Yes, both the pages have the pages_read_user_content permission. Infact its the same piece of code getting access tokens for both the pages.

Comment: Found the mistake. Turns out in my code I was passing the right page access token, but not changing the page id, hence for the second page the first page's id was getting sent. Thanks @luschn

Comment: yeah, that is why i mentioned "page token of the page in question" in my answer - instead of the id, you can also use /me instead, btw.